# Is it best to make all important functions in upgradable contracts virtual?

Tags: contract-upgrading

I want to be able to edit some functions during upgrades, and potentially solve errors. I can only override my previous function if it's virtual. Is it best to make all important functions virtual?

Comment: I can't understand what is your purpose, but if you wanna upgrade your smart contract to change functions you have to use a proxy, Does it help you?

Comment: I guess that might help. I'll have to look more into proxies. I guess I don’t know as much on it

Comment: with proxies, you can change your smart contract's functions but I suggest reading OpenZepplin docs to know which pattern is usable for you.
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy